# How to expand textboxes when using media="print"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print a web form and some textboxes have a set width and height but when I print I want to expand them so that I can see all the text that's in them on the print.

How can I do this?

I am already using a media="print" stylesheet to hide/change some other elements.

HTML example for multiline textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHistory" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="required" Columns="23" Rows="3"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jqprint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) and on print it automatically stretches the element your printing to the page width.  That should print out all your text, hopefully.